# Edit was approved - is actually new answer

Tags: support, suggested-edits

A [suggested edit on one of my answers was approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21834000), but the edit is actually an entirely new answer and I do not think it should have been approved. [The editor is a new user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10862513/dan) on Stack Overflow (at the time of this post)

[image]

Comment: Mistakes get made, note that only one user approved that edit, but because he improved it it got approved immediately. Because of that, I think this does not really need to be discussed here, a simple rollback is sufficient.

Comment: Are you concerned about the edit? About the approval? Do you want to know what to do about it? Not very clear what's the question here.

Comment: I'm not clear about it either. I like the contents of the edit, it's a great addition to the question. But it's just not an edit... So... Just thought I should bring it to attention.

Comment: iirc you can @ the editor in a comment and tell them to post it as an alternative answer to the question instead of editing it in. That, and performing a rollback on your own answer if you are not content with the edit.

Comment: As Erik mentioned, just roll it back. If you believe the reviewer has a track record of approving things they shouldn't, raise a custom mod flag so a ◆ can take a look. Otherwise not much meta can do about this, IMO.

Comment: +1 for rollback. I can make a guess you didn't do so yet because you want that second answer to exist and you want to give the editor a chance to own it, but maybe it already does somewhere else. If someone is unaware of the editing rules then they may also be unaware of the rules surrounding content duplication. There are too many what ifs, just do the one thing that is guaranteed correct.

Comment: I agree with @Codeer, you should simply inform the new user as they may continue doing things like this as they may not know right from wrong (in the case of SO standards). I think it's really the only thing that should be done.